# Discovering the last user to have logged on to Windows or Linux, from command line

Tags: linux, windows, script, login, authentication

Is it possible (and how) to tell which user and when was last logged in before the current user, via the command line interface? The ultimate goal is to write a script that writes this information to file.

Comment: In Linux just type `last` . No need for a `.sh`

Comment: Yes, @C0deDaedalus, Your comment is important. I've edited my question (added second sentence), to explain why script is needed.

Comment: In Windows, You may look in system logs for success 4624 event. To obtain that info from command line You may use any external command-line event viewer. PS. Formally the info about previos user logged in without sufficient rights is a security leak...

Comment: @ValerjansVinogradovs, updated my answer to concern the information writing to file. Also, Using [Cron Scheduling](https://www.tecmint.com/11-cron-scheduling-task-examples-in-linux/) for the task would be a better idea.

Comment: Not Sure, but In windows you could write a powershell script using [Get-Winevent](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-5.1#examples) commands.

Answer (score 2):

Not a Windows User, Thus would like to answer for Linux platform, where in you have already a built-in command known as `last`. You can write a `.sh` script If you want as an exercise, but I think using command would be a better idea. However,

### [last](https://linux.die.net/man/1/last) command

It gives you a listing of last user logged in and other important details as to time of login, system run-levels, etc.Just issue command to know what you want :

```
last
```

It should show something like this :

```
john     pts/0        :0               Mon Jun  4 09:20   still logged in
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-127-generi Mon Jun  4 09:18   still running
john     pts/1        :0               Sun Jun  3 09:41 - 10:30  (00:48)
john     pts/1        :0               Sun Jun  3 09:41 - 09:41  (00:00)
```

Follow [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36287/259047) to know what values in each columns stands for. To get more details, you can use parameters :

```
last -aFwx
```

where

- **-a** Displays the `hostname` in the last column, just makes the formatting better.
- **-F** prints **full** login-logout times and dates.
- **-w** shows full user names and domain names and
- **-x** shows the system shutdown entries and run level changes.

It would show something like this :

```
john     pts/1        Mon Jun  4 14:10:25 2018   still logged in                       :0
john     pts/0        Mon Jun  4 09:20:21 2018   still logged in                       :0
runlevel (to lvl 5)   Mon Jun  4 09:19:37 2018   still running                         4.4.0-127-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Jun  4 09:18:24 2018   still running                         4.4.0-127-generic
john     pts/1        Sun Jun  3 09:41:37 2018 - Sun Jun  3 10:30:29 2018  (00:48)     :0
```

---

To write information to a file, just **[redirect](https://askubuntu.com/a/420983/769206)** output of command to a file, say `last_users.log` by typing this :

```
last > last_user.log
```

OR

```
last -aFwx > last_user.log
```

Feel free to add-in more details.

Comment: Your answer is very good! However the command "last" without filtering gives too much information. Is it possible to filter it for showing not all, but only the last logging in or out events for each user at least for 5 (or less) users (if Linux)?

Comment: Yes, that is certainly possible using `grep` and `awk` commands. But that would be an answer to another question like `How to filter xyz column from "last" command output ? ` or something similar to that.

Comment: Therefore question was not about single command, but about a script.

Comment: But you **can** do all that in a single line command that can be put in a [cronjob](https://www.tecmint.com/11-cron-scheduling-task-examples-in-linux/) for the purpose. Then Why write the script ?

Comment: Ditto, e.g. `last | head -n 1 | cut -f 1 -d ' '`.